# How to increase font size in xdiskusage?

Tags: linux, x11

I have a 4k monitor so (not surprisingly) the text diskusage in xdiskusage is far too small.  Unfortunately, there is no single way to reset dpi in linux, and it is sometimes necessary to make application specific adjustments.

Does anyone know how to change the dpi and/or font size for xdiskusage?

FYI I've already implemented some 'generic' fixes:

- My ~.xprofile contains 'xrandr --dpi 157'
- My autostart file (I'm using openbox) contains 'xrdb -merge /home/moi/.Xresources'

These two things fix display problems for most apps.

Some QT apps need
'export QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO=2' but that doesn't work for xdisusage.

I'd appreciate any thoughts on this.

thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xdiskusage uses FLTK. In general there is not a way to increase the font size in FLTK applications, according to [Change GUI font size](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fltkgeneral/bA10njfviLM), though both that thread and [High DPI with FLTK](https://www.oyranos.org/2016/01/high-dpi-with-fltk/index.html) mention setting `FL_NORMAL_SIZE` to a larger value. `FL_NORMAL_SIZE` is set to 12 in [xdiskusage.C](https://sourceforge.net/p/xdiskusage/git/ci/master/tree/xdiskusage.C), though simply changing that and recompiling may not give the best results, as mentioned also in the “Change GUI font size” thread. Also, there are several places in xdiskusage.C that set font sizes at runtime, as well as one in panels.C, that may need to be changed.